# Knockout view model binding

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Lets say I have a table:

```
<table>
 <tr class="expandable">
  <td><button>Expand</button></td>
  <td>Parent information #1</td>
  <td>Parent information #2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="expandable">
  <td><button>Expand</button></td>
  <td>Parent information #1</td>
  <td>Parent information #2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I have a knockout template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="child-template">
 <!-- ko foreach: children -->
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>Child information #1</td>
   <td>Child information #2</td>
  </tr>
 <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

And some javascript

```
$('button').click(function() {
 $.getJSON(url, function(items) {
  var template = $('#child-template').html();
  $(this).closest('tr').after(template);
  var viewModel = { children: ko.observableArray(items) };
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
 });
});
```

What I want is a table that contains parent rows. If I click on a parent row, I call for it's children via ajax. When I get the children, I want to show a table for for every children under the parent row.

The problem with the above code is that I apply bindings to the entire page. What I really want is to bind that view model only to that parent row. If I first click parent row #1, it will show the correct children, but when I click parent row #2, both child lists will contain the same items.

I visualized my problem in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ehfb/1/

If you first click Expand on parent row #1, it will show Child item #1. When you click Expand on parent row #2, both children lists contain the same items. The children of parent row #1 should not be affected when Expanding parent row #2.

How to fix?

Answer (score 3):

A possible fix would be to define a single view model that contains a collection of parents.  This would mean each parent could have it own separate array of children.

```
function generateParent(name, id)
{
    function show() {
        this.expanded(true);
    }

    function initalDataCollection() {
        // Get data, add data to model
        // ...

        this.expanded(true);
        this.showAction(show);
    }

    return {
        expanded: ko.observable(false),
        information: ko.observable(name),
        children: ko.observableArray(),
        showAction: ko.observable(initalDataCollection)
    };
}

var viewModel = {
    parents: ko.observableArray()
};

//Add parent data to model
// ...

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I have provided a working solution that can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewDunsdon/khMG8/

HTML:

```
<table border="1" data-bind="foreach: parents">
     <tr class="expandable">
        <td>
            <button data-bind="visible: !expanded(), click: showAction() ">Expand</button>
            <button data-bind="visible: expanded(), click: function() { expanded(false) }">Hide</button>
         </td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: information"></span></td>
     </tr>
    <!-- ko if: expanded -->
    <!-- ko foreach: children -->
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td data-bind="text: info"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->

</table>
```

Side note: As part of this solution, I have let knockout handle onClick events ("expand" function) and updating the html on the page.